# "The specified network password is not correct." when trying to connect to Samba server

Tags: networking, server, password, samba, 17.10

I've just setup a samba server on Ubuntu Server 17.10. When I try to connect to this server on Windows 10, I get the error `The specified network password is not correct.`.

I am using the username `aaron` and the corresponding password for the account on Ubuntu. This is my current config file...

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    netbios name = fs.local

    security = user
    encrypt passwords = yes


#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[aaron]
    path = /home/aaron/share2
    valid users = @users
    map hidden = yes
    map system = yes
    writeable = yes
```

I don't know what's wrong with this config file, and after looking at many other answers I can't seem to find the problem.

PS: When connecting, I am using `\\fs.local\aaron` since that is the name defined in the samba config and it is the hostname of the device.
    Also I am using Windows 10 Home edition if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance for any help!